# Триггер для MySQL — записать в таблицу test весь SQL запрос

Tags: триггер, mysql

Предположим, мы имеем:
База данных MySql с таблицами table1 и test

Подскажите, существует ли возможность написать такой триггер, при котором все Update, Delete и Insert запросы к таблице table1 будут отслеживаться и полный "текст" самого запроса записываться в таблицу test (с id и таймстампом)?

Если это возможно, подскажите, как это называется и как искать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, под каждое действие, надо создавать отдельный триггер. Набросал вам триггер под UPDATE:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_upd`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `test_upd` BEFORE UPDATE ON `test`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE `original_query` VARCHAR(1024);
SET `original_query` = (SELECT `info` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE `id` = CONNECTION_ID());

INSERT INTO `test_log` VALUES
(NULL,
 OLD.`field_1`,
 OLD.`field_2`,
 OLD.`field_3`,
 `original_query`,
 NOW()
);
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

**test_upd** - имя триггера, **test** - таблица, на которую этот триггер вешаем, **test_log** - таблица, в которую будем складировать логи.

Создаёте, if not exists, таблицу "test_log" с необходимыми полями. Если смотреть на мой пример, а именно часть "*INSERT INTO `test_log`* ..." , то первое поле - id записи лога (PK, автоинкремент), далее три поля для данных основной таблицы `test` до апдейта (поля должны быть того же типа, что и в оригинале), предпоследнее поле - для хранения запроса и последнее - дата выполнения запроса.